# Any way to preserve phpWord placeholders when populating MS word content from MySQL database using php?

Tags: php, phpword

I am building a document workflow system (in PHP) which utilises word templates.
I will populate some content (document number, title, issue, and signatures) from a mySQL database. The rest of the document will be created by a user of the system in MS Word by downloading and filling it. When they have finished adding content they will upload to the system to collect signatures.

Due to the nature of the documents they will sometimes need to be revised (up issued) after the workflow has been completed.
To create a new revision, the existing document will be copied as the starting point. A new revision will need certain fields updated (that were filled from the database) and the signatures that were placed on the first version must be removed in order to collect new signatures for the new version.

I have managed to populate a template using phpWord with variables (using placeholders ${EXAMPLE}), but if I need to update the document (up issue after it has been completed by the user), the variable placeholder has been overwritten, and can no longer be written to by phpWord.

I therefore wonder if there is a way to use the MS Word content control fields to achieve this (but still using my existing mySQL database?
Or indeed any other way that would enable me to update fields in an MS Word document?

Comment: Just recreate the document from scratch rather than trying to figure out how to modify it

Comment: Just make sure that the placeholders in the word templates will not be overwritten when they are edited.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.